# Can anyone please explain what RowSize and PixelArraySize mean in BMP file format?

Tags: image-processing, pixel, bmp

I was writing a code for reading a BMP Image files, and I couldn't understand what `RowSize` and `PixelArraySize` mean or their operation, are these two formulas used for padding the row to a multiple of 4 bytes? Can anyone help me to understand this? Thanks a lot!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry if I made a mistake but I was writting c++ code for reading bmp images and I encoutered with a problem I mentioned above!

Comment: @MarcoBonelli _"I was writing a code for reading a BMP Image files, ..."_: that sounds like a programming question to me

Comment: @Alazar I think your question is perfectly valid. Programming is more than code, it is also about defining and understanding concepts. I am speaking from 35 years of experience.

Comment: From Wikipedia: _"Padding bytes (not necessarily 0) must be appended to the end of the rows in order to bring up the length of the rows to a multiple of four bytes. When the pixel array is loaded into memory, each row must begin at a memory address that is a multiple of 4. This address/offset restriction is mandatory only for Pixel Arrays loaded in memory. For file storage purposes, only the size of each row must be a multiple of 4 bytes while the file offset can be arbitrary"_.

Comment: There's no `PixelArraySize` in the equation.

Comment: Thanks for replying friends, so can anyone here interested in helping me?

Comment: @Alazar you should clarify your question because in its current state it's hard to understand what you are asking. There is no `PixelArraySize` in the formula you show. Also, no code which refers to such a variable. You should at least include more details. Also, the Wikipedia page for the BMP file format (which seems to be where you took the formula from) explains everything in detail.

Comment: Sorry my bad! I edited it!

Comment: Please use text (even for the formula) instead of including images.

Comment: @scrutari hard to convert that formula in text, but yeah the rest should be.

Comment: The second image pretty much answers your question. So it's hard to tell what you think is unclear.

Comment: Okay, what about the RowSize or why 31 is being added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is explained in the picture just below the formula, `RowSize` represents a single image row size in *bytes*, rounded (*padded*) to a nearest multiple of 4. This padding is often applied for performance reasons (memory alignment).

The formula shows 2 ways to calculate `RowSize`, *padded* to 4 bytes:

1. `ceil(BitsPerPixel * ImageWidth / 32) * 4` - take row size in bits, divide by 32 (i.e. 4 bytes), round **up**, then multiply by 4 to get the number in bytes
2. `floor((BitsPerPixel * ImageWidth + 31) / 32) * 4` - take row size in bits, add 31, divide by 32 (i.e. 4 bytes), round **down**, then multiply by 4 to get the number in bytes

You can see that the two ways are equivalent.

Version 2 is often preferred because rounding down in integer arithmetic happens implicitly:

```
int BitsPerPixel, ImageWidth;
. . .
int RowSize = ((BitsPerPixel * ImageWidth + 31) / 32) * 4; // Voila.
```

Now, `PixelArraySize` is just `RowSize` times the number of rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend this is what I was looking for, because I was substituting a values into the variables, then i ended up with a decimal point, this is where my confusion came from. thanks in advance brother.

Answer (score 0):

An image is an array of pixels.
Each pixel has a depth (**normally** 8 or 16 bits), the higher the value the brightest the pixel is. => this explains the `BitsPerPixel` in the equation.
So that Images can be stored and processed, they should **normally** have a storage size (not pixel size) that is multiple of 4. => if the rows are multiple or 4, no matter the high of the image, the image size will be multiple of 4. This is why you are finding the `RowSize` .

This is "easy" for black/white images, take in count that colored images **normally** have 3 values per pixel (for example the RGB format has a value for Red, another for Green and one for Blue) => they should also be kept multiple of 4

Comment: I said so much **normally** because there are image formats based in up to 64 bits pixel depth. Also, there are programs like RTMAPS capable of processing Images with a non-multiple-of-4 size (which probably makes it slow)

Comment: Oww thanks for the explanation, it helps a lot! so the equation does the padding also!